# Using Azure iot node sdk with SOCKS 5 proxy

Tags: node.js, azure, proxy, azure-iot-sdk

I'm using [Azure iot sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/device/core/readme.md) for sending data to Azure IoT Hub. It works, but now I need to get through a SOCKS 5 proxy.

The SDK has 3 transports: AMQP, MQTT and HTTP. Right now I'm using AMQP, but I'm open to switching to another transport.

I dont understand where I need to put the details for the proxy.
Can it be done using the [socksv5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socksv5) package?

Answer (score 0):

According the https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/node/device/samples/package.json, the socks 5 proxy has not been supported, you can leave your request in the issues in github repo at https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues, or leave in the azure feedback site at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback